# Find Videos Inside a Post

Tags: videos

What can be an efficient way to determine videos that may be embedded in a post?

If the embed code is directly added to a post, it is easy to determine using regular expressions but some plugins embed videos through shortcodes or in custom fields. In these cases, the actual embed code is added at the time of rendering the post.

Comment: Are you looking to find all the videos in a post no matter how they are included? What specific plugins are you talking about?

Comment: Let's say I am only looking for YouTube URLs in a post.

Answer (score 0):

This is the statement I am currently using to extract YouTube URLs from a post:

```
preg_match('|http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)|', $post->post_content, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` contains the ID of the first video. This may not cover all the YouTube URL formats, but it should give you a start.

Comment: This works only when the YouTube URL is included in the blog posts. Some plugin insert videos through short codes, custom fields and am looking to extract such URLs that aren't int he body.

Comment: Right, I thought that is what you wanted. But do you know exactly what methods you are using?